# Best method for an ETL Package to load all data initially and then next run to only load changes or new items

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-job

I am new to SSIS and would like the best method for an ETL package creation to load all data initially and then next run to only load changes or new items.  I will use the package on a schedule SQL job. I know that I could set SSIS package to truncate the destination table but for me that is a waste of resources and if large tables are concern the transaction log would be huge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually this is done by having something like a `LastUpdated` date in your source table. You then compare that to the `LastUpdated` value in your destination, and if the source record has a newer date, load it, if not, ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are more than one method to achieve that:

1. Adding a reference table that contains the last inserted ID (or primary key value), and this table must be update each time.
2. Using [Change Data Capture (CDC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/change-data-capture-ssis?view=sql-server-2017), you can refere to the this article for more information about it: [Introduction to Change Data Capture (CDC) in SQL Server 2008](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/) *(Note that the database must be configured to enable CDC - may not work with your situation)*
3. Adding a `LastUpdate` column to the table, and read only date where `LastUpdate` column value is higher than the last running SSIS job date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I also found that Slowly changing Dimension could also achieve this.